# How will our world change if all animals suddenly die?

Tags: humans, science-fiction, fauna

I am in the process of building a world where all animals suddenly die and only four types of creatures survive on planet Earth: humans, (green) plants, bacteria and fungi.

**The Question:**

I am interested in knowing how this would change the world. Specifically, the economic and cultural implications. Of course the impact would be extremely severe as animals are a vital part of our environments.

- Would humanity survive this blow? (Death of all farm animals and fish would mean a *lot* of food would be destroyed along with creating billions of dollars in loss). Would there be enough vegetables to feed the whole population?
- How severe would be the shock factor? Also, how would human culture and values change, both immediately and in the long run?

---

Comment: Hi Nevi, welcome to the site. The question you are mentioning is now closed, because it was deemed not suitable for the site. You can also check this [meta](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3367/are-the-questions-how-will-our-world-change-if-all-men-women-suddenly-die-o) question about it.

Comment: Hello, Nevi! Welcome to Worldbuilding SE! Unfortunately, both this question and the one you link to are Idea Generation Questions, and thus off-topic for the site. I would suggest you to check out the Help Center, to check out how WB.SE works. This is a really fun place to hang around, once you get the gist of it!

Comment: wow that's a big edit hahaha

Comment: @nevi you should change a little your premise: 100 ml in a ocean are a way too small quantity to have the effect you want, also if you start with the ipothesis that a single virus can kill an organism

Comment: Google won't have to keep improving the YouTube servers as quickly because the rate at which cat videos are uploaded will decrease dramatically.

Comment: Glad to be of service to a newcomer :) @Nevi In future try to ask questions which are direct (instead of asking general questions, ask precise questions) and try to keep the number of questions limited. This makes it easier for people to answer your questions and would help anyone in future who has the same question(s) as yours :)

Comment: @YoustayIgo - I believe that such an extensive edit on behalf of another user, to the point where you invent a back-story for them, etc. is completely unacceptable. Furthermore, the question is still far too broad. A user who'd been around the block, such as yourself, should know better. This edit has sparked a Meta conversation: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3416/how-to-handle-this-extensive-edit

Comment: @Nevi could you please let us know how you feel about this edit?  Normally we would reject such a major rewrite as changing the author's intent, but if you two talked about it and you're ok with it, that's different.  Thanks.

Comment: I removed the backstory, mainly because I, like others, thought it went way too far. If you thought it was okay Nevi, feel free to do do a rollback.

Comment: But either way, the answer to this question is **painfully** obvious. We would never survive due to our dependence on pollinating insects. Without pollination of our fruits and vegetables, our food supply screeches to an abrupt halt. With famine throughout the world, humans are dying left and right, spreading diseases and sparking conflict, eventually killing off a **very** high percentage of humanity.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I was really surprised by the edit because I didn't expect the editor to turn my question to something so good. I allowed him to edit, he made a really nice post, I was very glad, I don't think it is unacceptable. If I had found the edit bad, i would have rollbacked it, so no worries :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We all die.

Animals have huge impacts on ecosystems they are all intertwined.  Just killing off one animal from an area can have devastating effects on ecosystems.

Even right now we are on the brink of a crisis because pollinators are having systemic die-offs.  Killing off all bees on the planet alone could cause huge famines around the world.

So we all die (or so many that we basically have to start over)

Comment: I thought it was fairly agreed upon that even if a question seems too broad, which this one clearly is, it was best not to encourage the question by answering it.

Comment: I don't have a problem with broad questions.  I think bowlturner did a fine job of answering it.  The economic and cultural implications don't matter because we would all die fairly quickly.  Human values and morals would be as they always are in such an apocalypse, some people would share the last of their resources and others would steal as many resources as they could, but only for a short time because we all die.